# Stata: Groupwise regressions and ranking

Tags: stata

I am currently developing a sentiment index using Google search frequencies taken from Google Trends.

I am using Stata 12 on Windows.

My approach is as following:

1. I downloaded approx ~150 business-related search queries from Googletrends from Jan 2004 to Dec 2013
2. I now want to construct an index using the 30 at that point in time most relevant queries related to the market I observe
3. To achieve that I want to use monthly expanding backward rolling regressions of each query on the market
4. Thus I need to regress 150 items one-by-one on the market 120 times (12 months x 10 years), using different time windows and then extract the 30 queries with the most negative t-test.

To exemplify the procedure, if I would want to construct the sentiment for January 2010 I would regress the query terms on the market during the period from Jan 2004 to December 2009 and then extract the 30 queries with the most negative t-statistic.

Now I am looking for a way to make this as automatized as possible. I guess should be able to run the 150 items at once, and I can specify the time window using the time stamps. Using Excel commands and creating a do-file with all the regression commands in it (which would be quite large) I could probably create the regressions relatively efficiently (although it depends on how much Stata can handle - any experience on that?).

What I would need to make the data extraction much easier is a command which I can use to rank the results of the regression according to their t-statistics. Does someone have an efficient approach to this? Or has general advice?

Comment: This question is not a good fit for SO. You sketch an entire economics or business-related project and ask several strategic questions about coding. This is not a site either for discursive comment about coding strategy or for questions without code. You might get better advice on Statalist but this is likely to seem too much like a shopping list for any Stata-related forum I know.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it seeks help for an entire project without showing any coding effort. "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results"

Comment: ok thanks for pointing that out. I agree, on the one side I was looking for general advise on how to approach this kind of problem, but on the other side I specifically asked for how to automatically rank the results from he regression. If someone has advise on that part I would be most thankful.

Comment: Your specific question is buried in the general one. I have to say that it still does not match the requirement I quoted earlier (source was http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: ok will adpot. Again, thanks for pointing out. appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Stata, once you run a ttest, you can type `return list` and you will get scalars that stata stores. Once you run a loop you can store these values in a number of different ways. check out the `post` command.

Comment: No Problem at all. Happy to help.